# LINQ: Joining two objects, Coalesce on reference

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of Products (draft) that needs to matched against to the database (saved) and do some computation. They are the same object when we retrieve or created. It went well if I match the Reference1 (draft) to Reference1 (saved) and Reference2 (draft) to Reference2(saved), but they altered the the database table and have to modify the Object as well, where, they can override the Reference1 value by using the OverrideReference1 field. the OverrideReference1 is the high priority (if not empty) to use over the Reference1. I also used `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.OverrideReference1) ? s.Reference1 : s.OverrideReference1` on joining but no luck

I used the below code to query the results, but having an error when joining the two objects.

```
        var draft = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 1000, Reference1 = "RC1", OverrideReference1 = string.Empty, Status = "Draft", Reference2 = string.Empty },
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 2000, Reference1 = "RC2", OverrideReference1 = string.Empty, Status = "Draft", Reference2 = string.Empty  },
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 3000, Reference1 = "RC3", OverrideReference1 = string.Empty, Status = "Draft", Reference2 = string.Empty  },
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 3000, Reference1 = string.Empty, OverrideReference1 = string.Empty, Status = "Draft", Reference2 = "CC1"  },
        };

        var saved = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 500, Reference1 = "RC1", OverrideReference1 = "RC3", Status = "Saved" },
            new Product { ProductName ="Phone", Quantity = 3000, Reference1 = string.Empty, OverrideReference1 = string.Empty, Status = "Saved", Reference2 = "CC1"  },
        };

        var results = (from d in draft
                       join s in saved on new { d.Reference1, d.Reference2 } equals new { s.OverrideReference1 ?? s.Reference1, s.Reference2 }
                       select new Product
                       {
                           ProductName = d.ProductName,
                           Quantity = s.Quantity - d.Quantity,
                           Reference1 = d.Reference1,
                           Status = d.Status
                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column name must be set same your problem is when string is null used **"OverrideReference1"** this property.

Issue in this line :

```
    join s in saved on new { d.Reference1, d.Reference2 } equals 
new { s.OverrideReference1 ?? s.Reference1, s.Reference2 }
```

Update

```
join s in saved on new {
                        (string?)Reference1 = d.Reference1,
                        (string?)Reference2= d.Reference2 } equals 
                    new {(string?)Reference1 = s.OverrideReference1 ?? s.Reference1,
                         (string?)Reference2= s.Reference2 }
```

Code:

```
var results = (from d in draft
                   join s in saved on new {(string?)Reference1 = d.Reference1,(string?)Reference2= d.Reference2 } equals 
                   new {(string?)Reference1 = s.OverrideReference1 ?? s.Reference1,(string?)Reference2= s.Reference2 }
                   select new Product
                   {
                       ProductName = d.ProductName,
                       Quantity = s.Quantity - d.Quantity,
                       Reference1 = d.Reference1,
                       Status = d.Status
                   }).ToList();
```